# Fancybox to Not Activate if Dragged

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, fancybox-2

I'm using [NiceScroll](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll) to make a container draggable. It is essentially a schedule that is 'masked' out, and can be dragged left and right to see more of the day.

I am also using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) in order to pop up more information on each event on the schedule.

When you drag an area of the schedule that has no active event, everything is fine.  When you start dragging on an area that has an active event (.act), when you release drag, it opens the Fancybox. This is not desired-- I'd just like it to stop dragging and not open the Fancybox.

Is there some kind of comparison I can use in the open or beforeLoad function that I can use to cancel the actual opening of the box?  Something like if mousedown position is more than 10px away from mouse up position?

Here is the code I have for the active items:

```
$("#schedule .act").fancybox({
    openEffect:     'none',
    closeEffect:    'none',
    autoSize:       false,
    autoWidth:      false,
    autoHeight:     true,
    minHeight:      275,
    autoResize:     true,
    width:          500,
    padding:        [50, 60, 0, 60],
    arrows:         true,
    loop:           false,
    closeBtn:       '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;">Close</a>',

    beforeLoad: function() {        
        $time = $(this.element).data('time');
        $type = $(this.element).data('type');
        $titl = $(this.element).data('title');
        $desc = $(this.element).data('desc');
        this.content = "<span class='time " + $type + "'> " + $time + " </span>" + "<span class='title'>" + $titl + "</span>" + "<div class='desc'>" + $desc + "</div>";
    }
});
```

Comment: when you say, `drag an area` do you mean using the bars created by NiceScroll ? ... on desktop or mobile?

Comment: Using nicescroll's touch behavior, where you click and drag an element and move it around.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. The tough part was making getting the class to be removed.  I tried using hover states and then mouseleave, but when dragging started, the class wouldn't get removed (even though the mouse was off of the element) until after the drag was released.  My solution was to this before initializing my fancybox call:

```
var clickDrag;
$("#schedule .act").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
    clickDrag = $(this);
    $("#schedule .act").mousemove(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hovered");
    });
});
```

And then, inside the beforeLoad in the fancybox call, I added:

```
if (!($(clickDrag).hasClass("hovered") ) ) {
    $.fancybox.cancel();
    return;
}
```